# solving in a formal way to prove the non -existence of a limit

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

How can I show formally whether the following limit exists or not?
$$\lim_{(x, y, z) \to (0, 0, 0)} \frac{x^2+2y^2+3z^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$

I have tried to justify the non-existence of the limit by approaching with two curves such that the result is different, so the limit will not be unique:

Letting $f(x,y,z)$ be the function in the limit, I have that

$$\lim_{z \to 0} f(0, 0, z) = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{3z^2}{z^2} = 3$$
and
$$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x, 0, 0) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2}{x^2} = 1$$
which are not the same.

Comment: Yes, your method is correct!

Comment: You could try to improve your Latex.

Comment: If $x=ka, y=kb, z=kc $, limit = 6